# what are the files supported by lucene-core 3.4.0 in java

Tags: java, lucene

Sorry for this question.In my project using lucene-core 3.4.0 for that support only for text files otherwise it's support all the files regard pdf,txt,ppt,xls.please provide information to me.otherwise which version support all files.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Apache SOLR in stead. Lucene is not some magic box which supports all and everything, it is a low level API to do blindingly fast indexing of data. What you want is a high level framework on top of that - which is SOLR.